# Perl Regex Multiple Capture Groups

Tags: regex, perl

I am never going to say I am an expert at regex and I am having an issue with this one I am sure due to my lack of understanding. If someone could please try and explain to me how to handle this situation I would really appreciate it.

```
string = "hello.world with_args, and_more_args #plus a comment
```

**Regular Expression**

```
/^\w*\.(\w+)\s+(.*?)([^#]*)$/
```

**Groups**

```
1. world
2. with_args, and_more_args #
3. plus a comment
```

The output I am hoping for is

```
1.world
2.with_args, and_more_args
3.#plus a comment
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated and if you could teach me something along the way i certainly won't complain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this:

```
^\w*\.(\w+)\s+(.*?) *(#[^#]*)$
```

#### [Online Demo](http://regex101.com/r/bO3rC7)

- To capture `#` in last group it is important to include `#` in your last capture group i.e. `(#[^#]*)`.
- I added `*` between group # and #3 to avoid capturing trailing space in 2nd group.

Comment: Thank you I knew I had to be close. I really appreciate the help and the lesson

Comment: You're welcome, glad it worked, yes your regex was pretty close.

Answer (score 2):

It is probably best to check for non-hash characters in the second capture; otherwise the pattern will match only lines with a comment.

I suggest this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $s = 'hello.world with_args, and_more_args #plus a comment';

$s =~ / \w*\.(\w+) \s+ ([^#]*) (#.*)? /x;

print "$_\n" for $1, $2, $3;
```

**output**

```
world
with_args, and_more_args 
#plus a comment
```

Comment: Thank you for the note. I did actually figure out that section my self (after must frustration) but I certainly appreciate the effort.